# Pandas Groupby-- How to extract first, last, or first non-NaN value from a group

Tags: pandas, group-by, aggregate

This comes up for me repeatedly, and I'm sure there a way to do it as part of the groupby().agg() command, but I can't figure it out. I often have to resample time series and need to keep a value from some non-numerical row, sometimes the 'DateTime' index, sometime a 'Name' column, etc.

Original df--

[image: Original df]

This line below, e.g., works great at converting a dataframe with columns 'Name', 'Price', 'Volume', into a 1min time series:

```
1_min_df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="1T")).agg({'Price': 'ohlc', 'Volume': 'sum'})
```

[image]

The problem is that I've entirely lost any all the 'Name' information. For each 1min grouping it's generally ok to grab the first, last, or any non-NaN value from 'Name'. I don't know how to get it and include it in the resulting data frame though.

Here's another variation of the same problem. This line below works great at grouping rows (using the bar function) that group rows with cumulative totals of about 1000 'Volume'. But I need to grab the 'DateTime' value of the first row of each group and keep the that value in a 'DateTime' column for the resulting grouped row.

```
vol_1000_df = df.groupby(bar(np.cumsum(df_concat['Volume']), 1000)).agg({'Price': 'ohlc', 'Volume': 'sum'})
```

[image: volume result]

I tried various additional parameters to the agg() function like, 'Name':'head' or 'DateTime':'tail' but nothing I've tried works.

Comment: make minimal example code(not image) and desired output https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you have to use `'Name': 'first'` in `agg` to keep the information about `Name`:

```
>>> (df.groupby(df.index.floor('1min'))
       .agg({'Name': 'first', 'Price': 'ohlc', 'Volume': 'sum'}))

                      Name   Price                         Volume
                      Name    open    high     low   close Volume
DateTime                                                         
1997-09-10 00:06:00  ESU97  934.00  934.00  934.00  934.00      0
1997-09-10 00:13:00  ESU97  933.75  933.75  933.75  933.75      0
```

As suggested by @mozway, if you want to group also by `Name`, you can use:

```
>>> (df.groupby([df.index.floor('1min'), 'Name'])
       .agg({'Price': 'ohlc', 'Volume': 'sum'}))

                            Price                         Volume
                             open    high     low   close Volume
DateTime            Name                                        
1997-09-10 00:06:00 ESU97  934.00  934.00  934.00  934.00      0
1997-09-10 00:13:00 ESU97  933.75  933.75  933.75  933.75      0
```

Comment: If there are several names (tickers?) it might also make sense to use Name as second grouper

Comment: Fantastic! I apparently tried everything but that, thanks! And is there a way to preserve the DateTime in the second case where each group is created based upon volume? Trying: ....agg({'DateTime':'last', 'Price': 'ohlc', 'Volume': 'sum'}) just gives an error that "Column(s) ['DateTime'] do not exist.

And will I need to add a function to the agg() call in the first case if there are NaNs scattered in among the names, so that I grab the first non-NaN Name?

Thanks!

Comment: `DateTime` column does not exists because `DateTime` is the index of your dataframe. Try a `reset_index()` before `groupby`.